# WPF TabControl - getting notification of a particular tabitem being opened?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

I'm using WPF 4
I have a TabControl that contains a bunch TabItems.
I want to be notfied when one tab in particular is opened/selected. 
I wrongly assumed that there would be something like "OnTabItemChanged" type event but I can't find anything like this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `SelectionChanged` event on the `TabControl`

Example of usage

**Xaml**

```
<TabControl ...
            SelectionChanged="tabControl_SelectionChanged">
```

**Code behind**

```
private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
    TabItem tabItem = tabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;
    //...

    // Or...
    //if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    //{
    //    TabItem selectedTabItem = e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem;
    //}
}
```